# Como hacer que me muestre la cantidad de números que aparecen en una cadena

Tags: java, string, bucles

Veo que me falta que me expresen solo los numeros ya pueden se de un digito o mas.
Yo solo he conseguido que me muestren los digitos y no los numeros.
Utilidades.dividirEnPalabras(cadena). Hace separar las palabras y ponerlas en un array, por eso tengo dos bucles unos para recorrer la array y otro para recorrer la palabra.

```
    String cadena = "un 20 i 23";
    String palabras[] = Utilidades.dividirEnPalabras(cadena);
    int contador = 0;
    boolean esDigito = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < palabras.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < palabras[i].length(); j++) {
            if(Character.isDigit(palabras[i].charAt(j))){
                contador++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No veo mal la propuesta que haces con los dos bucles, pero dentro de los bucles solo incrementas un contador, eso no sirve para resolver tu ejercicio. Además, el código proporcionado si bien no cumple con lo pedido en el ejercicio **no tiene ningún error**. No podemos ayudarte si no tienes un error, y no vamos a hacer el ejercicio por ti puesto que no aprenderías. Lo más importante no es *saber escribir código*, si no *saber qué código escribir*, y eso solo lo vas a aprender a base de intentarlo una y otra vez. Dale vueltas, intenta algo, y si tienes un error, pregunta :)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer uso de expresiones regulares(Regex) para encontrar numeros en una cadena

-? coincide con un signo negativo inicial,opcionalmente para numeros negativos

\d + coincide con 1 o más dígitos.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
 import java.util.regex.Matcher;
 public class Test{
           
 public static int numeroEnFrase(String cadena){
   int cont=0;
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
       Matcher m = p.matcher(cadena);
       while (m.find()) {
             cont++;
              }
              return cont;
             }
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String cadena="un 20 i 23 4 5 70 90";
        
        System.out.println(numeroEnFrase(cadena));
        
        }}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: si te ayudo la respuesta,marcala como aceptada para poder seguir ayudando a otros usuarios.Saludos cordiales